# Confusing NPM dependency error with Karma

Tags: npm, karma-runner

I've run into a peer dependency issue in Node Package Manager and the error doesn't make sense to me.

`npm ERR! peerinvalid The package karma@0.13.19 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-jasmine@0.2.3 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.2.3 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-karma@0.5.4 wants karma@~0.9.4 || ~0.10`

To me this says that Karma 0.13.19 is installed and karma jasmine requires a version of Karma greater then or equal to 0.9.

If this is correct then why would I receive an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that my problem was I wasn't reading the whole error message. As the packages below only accepted up to minor version 0.10 and therefore my version was too high.